# date plot in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a csv file containing date as below

Date,Quantity

"Apr 16, 2007",383

"Apr 17, 2007",448

.
.

I want to plot this using pgfplots, but I am not sure how to specify the format "Apr 16, 2007". pgfplots seems to have a problem understanding this.

Comment: Have a look at the `dateplot` library.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For that you should have a look at the `dateplot` library of PGFPlots ([section 4.21.2 on page 364 in the manual v1.13](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=364)).

Here is one of the given examples, where I only put the data into a CSV file. Some more hints on how to use it are given in the comments of the code.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        pgfplots.dateplot,
    }
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
    date, value
    2009-08-18 09:00, 50
    2009-08-18 12:00, 100
    2009-08-18 15:00, 100
    2009-08-18 18:35, 100
    2009-08-18 21:30, 40
    2009-08-19, 20
    2009-08-19 03:00, 0
    2009-08-19 06:00, 35
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            date coordinates in=x,
            date ZERO=2009-08-18,   % <-- needs to be set for v1.12 and below
            xmin=2009-08-18 06:00,
            xmax=2009-08-19 09:00,
            % set `xtick distance' to 3 hours (3/24)
            xtick distance=0.125,
%            % alternatively you could use every given date as `xtick'
%            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style={
                rotate=90,
                anchor=near xticklabel,
            },
            % set the label style of the `xtick's
            xticklabel=\day.\month.\year\ \hour:\minute,
        ]
            \addplot table [col sep=comma,x=date,y=value] {data.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Any suggestion on how to handle "Apr 6, 2007" date format. This is where I am stuck

Comment: @anup, you mean you want to stick to the given date format? I would there is no chance to stick to that using PGFPlots. You have to transform them to the international date format ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)). This should be pretty easy for example using Excel.